# Replace yum with apt

Tags: yum, aptitude

I have used Ubuntu for like two years now. I am very comfortable with the aptitude package manager. I recently switched to Fedora(16)[I still have ubuntu on my other drive :) ]
I am behind a university firewall (with all kind of data restrictions). In these circumstances I realized apt is better suited and effective when compared to yum. How can I replace yum with apt??

Comment: Wait, what? Do you understand the difference between the two? Why is one "better" than the other? You can't replace package managers (sanely) and expect to have a working system. Besides, Ubuntu and Fedora's package structures differ.

Comment: um... apologies! What i meant was the installer. It's been just two weeks since I installed fedora! Whenever i use yum,updates/primary_db and some more,will update themselves. I have to wait for them to update and with the restrictions we have it is very annoying(most of them stop midway). With apt that was not the case. I went ahead and installed apt (which is what i wanted basically...). Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

See:

http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/apt2yum

...replacing the distribution package manager is *not* a good idea.

Comment: ... unless you what?

Comment: Bad edit. Thought about qualifying it a bit, for the 1% of cases where it might be better ... but decided it was too much trouble to make sure people didn't take it as a 90% solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

While this is *technically* possible, it is an awful idea.

However, if all you want is an `apt`-like frontend for `rpm`, there once was [apt-rpm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APT-RPM) - but seems that it is dead (the project has not released anything in 4 years). You'd be better off just learning `yum`.